# Fedora 19 using rpmfussion's NVIDIA driver: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Tags: opengl, fedora, nvidia, egl, glx

When running an app that uses Qt 4.7 on my Fedora 19 box I am getting the following errors from the application:

```
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so 
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/Matthew.Hoggan/.drirc: No such file or directory. 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast ERROR: Error failed to create progam.
```

I do not see these errors in a stock X11 application where the context is configured using glx. I am assuming this is because Qt uses egl underneath. The same thing happens when using the EGL 3 emulator from http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/tools/opengl-es-3-0-emulator/ while running their cube example.

I have already verified that both xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.i686 and yum install xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.x86_64 rpms are installed.

My system information is:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.11.9-200.fc19.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 20 21:22:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And glxinfo is:

```
[Matthew.Hoggan@localhost QtTest]$ glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 331.38
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.38
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
```

Any suggestions here or is more information needed?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use EGL in the first place? You clearly have a X server and GLX installed on this system, falling back to a software rasterizer for EGL/GLES hardly makes any sense. Furthermore, if you use the proprietary driver from NV, they implement [`GL_EXT_glx_create_Context_e2_profile`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/glx_create_context_es2_profile.txt). It will not get you EGL, but functionally you will have what amounts to a pseudo-ES2 implementation.

Comment: Yes my work environment requires it. And by default that is what Qt uses. In applications that I write outside of my work environment I already have a cross platform solution that exchanges wgl end glx functions.

Comment: I am getting the same issue on F20. I am also experiencing screen flickering and I suspect the issues are related.

Comment: Exact same issue for F20 running in VMWare VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to get rid of the same error messages for octave-4.0.0-rc1 which also use Qt. The bug hunting history can be found [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44467).

It turned out to be an **incorrect runpath** in a shared library (.so). The runpath contained /usr/lib64. Hence at runtime the /usr/lib64/libGL.so was loaded, instead of the right nvidia /usr/X11R6/lib64/libGL.so.

### Workaround

1. Find the lib or executable which has the incorrect runpath with `ldd <app or lib>` and `chrpath -l <app or lib>`
2. Replace the wrong path with the correct one (without the offending /usr/lib64) using `chrpath -r <correct path> <app or lib>`
   The following one-liner did this for liboctgui.so. Just replace "liboctgui.so" by your value.
   `chrpath -r $(chrpath -l liboctgui.so | cut -d '=' -f '2' | awk '{gsub(/\/usr\/lib64/, "")}; 1') liboctgui.so`

### Origin

The incorrect runpath was picked up at compilation time from an irrelevant
`-L/usr/lib64` in `libQt*.la` files located in /usr/lib64.
The [comment #18](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44467#comment18) explains why it is wrong.

And indeed, `lib*.la` files should not be packaged, according to [OpenSUSE own recommendations](https://en.opensuse.org/Shared_Library_Packaging_Policy)

> Avoid packaging libtool config files (.la files). If you do not
>   package a static library, and if you are also placing the shared
>   library in a standard search directory (i.e. %_lib, /usr/%_lib), they
>   will not be needed.

Removing `lib*.la` from /usr/lib64 and rebuilding fixed the problem for good.