# serious issue to start OpenGl application from QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt-creator, qt5

my platform is fedora 21 x64 with QT 5.4 qtcreator 3.3.0

my graphic card is NVS4100 and install NVIDIA driver with OpenGl support.

1. when i execute compiled opengl app outside of qtcreator, it's works
2. when i do the same from qt-creator i receive error messages:

   libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found

   libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

...
after some investigation, i found QProcess::start use by qtcreator add /usr/lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the environment which break the correct localisation indicated by the linker (with command ldd) (libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fe25ca7d000ich

how i can change that?
all tentatives to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH from qtcreator failed, Qprocess::start append /usr/lib64 in front of it?

Comment: Quick'n dirty workaround would be to drop it in your application. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655717/fedora-19-using-rpmfussions-nvidia-driver-libgl-error-failed-to-load-driver

Comment: ok, i do finish the nvidia driver installing job by hand **# mv libGL.so libGL.so.nonvidia ** **#mv  libGL.so.1 libGL.so.1.nonvidia** **ln -s /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.1 libGL.so.1** **ln -s /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.1 libGL.so** work like acharm, thanks

Comment: Yes, the "good" old symlinking to nastily work something around, but the your original concern is valid. I hope someone knows the real answer for it. Is it reproducable on other distributions, though?

Comment: better approach to strip annoying /usr/lib64 append to LD_LIBRARY_PATH **1) find and copy your LD_LIBRARY_PATH ** **2) inside QtCreator, goto Projects -> Kit -> Run -> Run environment and edit and paste your expected LD_LIBRARY_PATH value ** works too

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the basic problem in the following bug report:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8727

Apparently, Qt needs fixing in the function/method called DesktopQmakeRunConfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error using OpenSuse 42.1 and Qt Creator 5. Error started after using the community NVidia repo to update the video drivers. Apparently you'll only have this error if you're using a 64bit linux distro. I was able to fix it by editing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in QT Creator from /usr/lib64 to /usr/lib

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with fedora 19 x64 and Qt 5.3.2.

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

As you pointed out, LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems to mess up the localisation of the right library ( /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 instead of  /usr/lib64/nvidia/libGL.so.1).

In my case, this was caused by the following line adding an external library in my .pro file:

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L/usr/lib64 -lrt

To avoid ambiguous paths and solve the issue, I specified the name of the library I needed to link with:

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L/usr/lib64/**librt.so** -lrt

After this the libGL error vanished !! (and I was still able to link with librt.so)

Answer (score 0):

On openSUSE 13.2

I could change "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" in the "Run configuration" of the project or in a more general place, in "Settings > Options > Buid & Run > Kits > Environment", to nothing or to the path for AMD proprietary driver "libGL.so": "/usr/X11R6/lib64/" and the openGL programs run without error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I ssh into my Ubuntu VM from my Macbook Pro.  Installing the below driver on my Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit OS resolved the issue for me. Hope this helps someone.

sudo apt-get install nvidia-331

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on Arch Linux various times. The mentioned errors prevented to program to start:

> libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
>
> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

A possible quick solution that worked in my case was to LD_PRELOAD the right library:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/nvidia/libGL.so' <program>
```

/usr/lib/nvidia/libGL.so pointed to the correct libGL:

```
$ namei /usr/lib/nvidia/libGL.so
f: /usr/lib/nvidia/libGL.so
 d /
 d usr
 d lib
 d nvidia
 l libGL.so -> libGL.so.1
   l libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.340.107
     - libGL.so.340.107
$ file /usr/lib/nvidia/libGL.so.340.107
/usr/lib/nvidia/libGL.so.340.107: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had a similar problem with QtCreator 4.5.2, I could resolve it by unchecking `Add build library search path` under `Projects -> Build & Run -> Run Settings -> Run`.